# What is the modern way to develop a Linux auditing kernel module?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, linux-audit

I'm new to Linux Kernel development, and I am now assigned a task to develop a Linux kernel module, which can monitor the network, filesystem, USB and serial ports.

I am aware of the things like netfilter/iptables, libpcap, inotify and lse (linux security modules). I know there is always more than one way to skin a cat, especially in Linux world.

I am still wondering, what the proper way to do auditing things in Linux kernel nowadays is.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `auditd` is a popular+modern approach to auditing such things.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Audit_framework